# Bandwidth Throttle for linux

Tags: linux, bandwidth, web-development, throttling

The [Throttle Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5917) doesn't work on linux.

Is there a utility for linux that could throttle the bandwidth usage for a particular program/process, or even the entire system?

Main usage would be for web development, to test the user experience when the connection is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was also asked on Stack Overflow. Have a look through the answers: [**how to throttle bandwidth on a linux network interface**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface).

Answer (score 2):

[trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle) is what you're after.

Comment: Not exactly what I need. I need to be able to change the limitation while firefox is running.